# Mariadb: Pagination using OFFSET and LIMIT is skipping one row

Tags: php, mariadb

I have this MariaDB table:

id, name

The id column has these attributes: Primary, auto_increment, unique.

The table has 40,000 rows.

I'm using this PHP & MariaDB to load rows from this table.
This is the PHP code:

```
$get_rows = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table where id> 0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 30 OFFSET ?");
$get_rows->bind_param('i', $offset);
//etc.
```

The query returned everything correctly at the first time, but in the next query (made through AJAX), I received the next 30 rows with a gap of one row between the current result and the next one. And this goes on and on.

In the table, the row #1 had been deleted. So, I restored it, and now the query works. However, I will definitely have to delete more rows in the future. (I don't have the option of soft-deleting).
Is there any way I can keep deleting rows, and have these queries return correct results (without skipping any row)?

**EDIT**

Here's an example of the range of the ids in the first 2 queries:

Query 1:

247--276

Query 2:

278--307

(277 is missing)

NB I asked ChatGPT, but it couldn't help. :')

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly; are you wondering why your offset doesn't match the _next_ 30 results, if you delete rows before fetching them?

Comment: I'm not deleting rows. They're already deleted, and more are going to be deleted in the future.

Comment: I've just added an example to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIMIT and OFFSET query rows by position, not by value. So if you deleted a row in the first "page," then the *position* of all subsequent rows moves down by one.

One solution to ensure you don't miss a row is to define pages by the greatest `id` value on the preceding page, instead of by the offset.

```
$get_rows = $conn->prepare("
  SELECT * FROM my_table where id> ? 
  ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 30");
$get_rows->bind_param('i', $lastId);
```

This only works if your previous query viewed the preceding page, so you can save the value of the last id in that page.